# How to check user is actively present or not in react native?

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I want to check that user is active or not at application level.I have used PanResponder to detect user activity for one screen but I want to check for whole application in one component because I have more than 20 screens in application.
Note: I am using wix-react-native-navigation for navigation so every new screen is in navigation stack.

Comment: have you tried using pan responder with your root component?

Comment: Yes but it works only for root component.

Comment: components in stack are not affected by pan responder